How to set the start of a video to 0 with FFmpeg?
I set custom PTS on an MP4 video but the starting point of the output video is not 0.
As shown by the ffprobe:
Duration: 00:00:05.00, start: 0.033008, bitrate: 2638 kb/s

Is there a way to set the starting point to 0 using FFmpeg?
EDIT:
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[v]setpts='(0*eq(N,-1)+330*eq(N,0)+191*eq(N,1)+211*eq(N,2)...)'[out]" -map [out] out_video.mp4

I was starting with frame ID -1 instead of 0. This makes the PTS of the first frame greater than 0.
